# WP 7.1 app shows thich Black header while running in WP8 emulator

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

i have developed an windows phone app in WP7.1, while running in WP8.0 it is showing a thick black top border,
here is my code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="MapTestApp7.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Blue">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

here is the link to output image :
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By0Y-Dca1cKjWUJ3emtPZHVDbVk/edit?usp=sharing

please help me in removing the top border.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way of removing that border for a WP7 running on WP8 720p device.
If you don't want the border, you need to convert your WP7 project to WP8.

Explanation:

WP7 apps are constrained in a 480*800 container that is scaled up when running on 768*1280 or 720*1280 Windows Phone 8 devices.

On 768*1280 devices (WXGA), the scale ratio is 1.6x => no border.

On 720*1280 devices (720p), the scale ratio is 1.5x with a 80px black border at the top (53px after scaling).

Comment: i have upgraded my solution to WP8.0, but still black top is visible.

Comment: In design mode or in the emulator?

Comment: in visual studio 2012, we have an option to upgrade out solution to WP8.0

Comment: Yes, but do you still have the black border when running the app on the 720p emulator or only on the designer view?

Comment: in designer view i don't have any border, but while running in emulator 720P, it comes.

Comment: That's weird, I copy/pasted your XAML into a new WP8 project, no border in 720p. Try creating a new WP8 project from scratch.

Comment: ohk thanks. but is there any way to remove that top border having WP7.1 solution ?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, there is no way to remove the border on a WP7 app running on a 720p WP8. The app needs to be a WP8 app to make use of the entire screen.

Answer (score -1):

Change d:DesignHeight="768" to d:DesignHeight="800"

That should do the trick.

Br,

Comment: :In Emulator 720P, that thick black top is still visible.

Comment: In that case you'll have to create a separate WP8 app. Wp7 apps scale differently on 720p (as explained by Olivier below)