# App is not loading as full screen in Windows Phone 7 1280x720 resolution

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, resolution

[image]

Left image is of app supported with both Windows phone 7 & 8 OS. 
Right image is of app supported with windows phone 8 OS only.

I really don't understand why this gap is left in app developed to support both OS. Both apps are newly created app with just background color change. There is no extra coding at all.

I've measured the gap's height and it is 80 pixel.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP 7.1 app shows thich Black header while running in WP8 emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528001/wp-7-1-app-shows-thich-black-header-while-running-in-wp8-emulator)

Answer (score 2):

All differences between Windows Phone 7 and Windows phone 8 screen-size (resolution) are explain [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). (in the MSDN websites, with samples).

On windows phone, you must manage all screen resolutions... If you have a project Windows Phone 7 by default, your screen size is adapted to this project and you are on WVGA (480 * 800). And, if you don't manage all size screen, on the Windows Phone device (or emulator) in 720p, you are a part of black screen on the top of your applications.

For informations:
Windows Phone 7 devices just manage

```
 - the WVGA resolution (480*800)
```

Windows Phone 8 devices manage three screen sizes:

```
 - the WVGA resolution (480*800)
 - the WXGA resolution (768 × 1280)
 - the 720p resolution (720 × 1280)
```

// rumors Part

And, Maybe with Windows phone 8 and GDR3 update, Windows Phone 8 manage one  additional screen size

```
 - the 1080p resolution (1080*1920)
```

// End rumors part